# Importing a dump file to MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have been trying to import a dump file which I created on a database that contains a table with virtual columns on a server MariaDB version 10.1.9. Here is part of the .sql file :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `abc`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `abc` (
`a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`b` int(11) AS ((`a` + 1)) VIRTUAL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
-- Dumping data for table `abc`
LOCK TABLES `abc` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `abc` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `abc` VALUES (2,3),(3,4),(3,4),(56,57);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `abc` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Now since MySQL latest version supports virtual columns, I expected the import to be successful but it failed giving an error:

```
Error Code: 3105 - The value specified for generated column 'b' in table 'abc' is not allowed.
```

Is there any way this error can be averted? And I can import the dump file to with the data to MySQL server version 5.7.11??

Comment: Sorry for asking something so obvious but... Have you checked the documentation to verify that the syntax for virtual columns is the same in both programs? (More specifically, can you **insert** actual values in virtual columns.)

Comment: Yes I have, I know I cannot import values in virtual columns. But that is what I am asking.. Is there a work around? any way possible?

Comment: Make the column a normal column, load dump, remove column, alter table to add it as virtual.

Comment: Meanwhile, file a bug: http://bugs.mysql.com saying that dump+reload fails when virtual columns exist.  (Looks like MariaDB thought about the problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Alvaro.. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked on Version 10.1.10 and this works good. i created first the Table with your CREATE and the i dump it and import it.

```
-- MySQL dump 10.16  Distrib 10.1.10-MariaDB, for osx10.11 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: bernd
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.1.10-MariaDB-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `abc`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `abc`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `abc` (
  `a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` int(11) AS ((`a` + 1)) VIRTUAL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `abc`
--

LOCK TABLES `abc` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `abc` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `abc` VALUES (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(99,100);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `abc` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2016-02-15 13:50:24
```